# php file public write risk

Tags: php, permissions, file-permissions

I have a file, I have to set it to public read and public write to work.  Under the two filetypes below, what are the risks of having it set to "public write"?

1 - Its a text file (.txt)

2 - Its a php file (.php)

Can the hackers do some damage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### PHP file

If php file is

1. accessible to apache,
2. apache is configured to process "*.php" files,
3. writable by anyone,

then it's a disaster waiting to happen. Try not to ask what may be done.

### Text file

If it's a regular apache setup it's rather safe.

Comment: how is the php situation a disaster?  Can you explain further please?  What type of attack can I expect?  A link is fine.

Comment: Hacker may execute his code on your host. Effects may vary: from adding your box to botnet to deleting everything on your box.

Comment: How can he access my box remotely?  Does public write literally mean he can make a php file on HIS box, which "includes" mine, or fopen's mine?

Comment: He can do just http call. He could just upload his php file and if that setup conforms previously mentioned circumstances it will be limited by his imagination.